# iRobot Create not returning sensor data

Tags: streaming, robotics, sensors, pyserial

I am trying to stream sensor data from the iRobot Create. I get tuple out of range errors when I try
bot.stream_sensors(somenumber) and bot.poll_sensors(somenumbers). Whenever I input bot.sensors, I just get an empty array {}. I have even tried sending bot.sensors while pushing in on the bump sensor, still getting an empty array. I am connected to the bot through the Serial port with a serial-to-usb converter on my side. The only code before trying to get the sensor data is 
import openinterface
bot = openinterface.CreateBot(com_port="/dev/ttyUSB0", mode="full")

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this issue? Everywhere else just uses stream_sensors(6) and it seems to work fine.

P.S. I posted a question similar to this topic not too long ago, but no one responded. Not trying to spam, but now I have a more clear question and what the apparent-problem is so I thought I would try again.

Comment: I think I just came from that question. If you feel you're new question is closely related to your old one, then you can edit your older question to include the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded openinterface.py from this [site](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~robotics/cs54/index.php/Python_setup#iRobot_Create_Open_Interface_Python_bindings): which included some sample programs. I'd suggest you take a step back, try the sample code, try to find other, more sophisticated, sample code and play with that first before moving on to your real code. You may be missing a step somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late to answer this, but for reference purposes.  Directly controlling the iRobot is simplified greatly by using 
[Pyrobot](http://pyrorobotics.org/?page=The_20Pyrobot_20Simulator).